# Adding JS function to onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I am currently trying to make three buttons that will call the same function, but will result with three different outcomes. This is what I have so far:

html

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="progressStatus(load)">Loading</button>
  <button class="btn btn-warning" onClick="progressStatus(warning)">Slow Connection</button>
  <button class="btn btn-danger" onClick="progressStatus(error)">Error Message</button>
</div>
<div class="progress-margin">
  <h2 id="progress-h2">Your Progress</h2>
  <div id="progress-bar">
    <div id="myBar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function progressStatus(status) {
    let elem = document.getElementById("myBar")
    let width = '';
    let bgColor = '';
    let innerText = '';
    // if error
    if (status==error) {
      width = 100;
      bgColor = red;
      innerText = "Something is wrong! Error";
    }
    
    // if slow
    if (status==warning) {
      width = 100;
      bgColor = yellow;
      innerText = "Slow Connection";
    }
    // if load
    if (status==load) {
      function frame() {
        
      }
      elem.style.width = width;
      elem.style.backgroundcolor = bgColor;
      elem.innerHtml = innerText;
      console.log() = status;
    }
  }
```

Now, before I even continue working with the code, I wanted to see if I could get the click event on the error button to just register a console.log(). But, unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: progressStatus is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (/:14:76)
```

I know that I'm missing something.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong with your code there. I just tested your code and it works perfectly fine without any errors.

Comment: what is the  value of `load` in `progressStatus(load)`  ? and where is it defined ?

Comment: Even when you click on the "Error" button? That's the one I'm testing right now.

Comment: Do you  need to include the script in the html page using a `<src>` tag?

Comment: @MisterJojo, That's what I was trying to figure out. I'm trying to make my function be `function progressStatus(status) { }`, where the three buttons will replace `status` with either `error`, `warning`, or `load`.

Comment: @Ethan please see my answer

Comment: @PaulRooney, I do, I'm sorry that I didn't include that part of the code, I just copied the necessary script to ask this question. As this is my first question on here, would it be better to include the whole HTML?

Comment: it would be better to include a snippet

Comment: Actually it probably is best to include as much information as you can. So we can rule out as many things as possible and recreate your issue reliably at our end.

Comment: @PaulRooney... Gosh-darn extra letter... i had typed `scripts.js` instead of `script.js`. Thank you. That has fixed one problem, while @Matthias' answer helped me fix a different problem. Onto the next issues. Thank you everyone that pipped in.

Comment: Common mistake. Everyone has done that at some point or other. If this kind of mysterious error occurs it can help to put a console log statement at the top of the js file and if that doesnt print, you know somethings not right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A seperate issue I see is that the JavaScript thinks that you are talking about variables when you type `load`, `warning` and `error`. Rather use double quotes around each one to define the text as a string:

```js
if (status=="load") {
      function frame() {       
}
```

In the mean time, check that your script file is correctly linked.